# Flutter listener error The argument Type can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, listener

Im starting learning flutter, and i've coding an app that contains some ads like intersticial from AdMob.

Im guiding myself from a YouTube video [this is the video](https://youtu.be/zall-SrUPb0?t=568)
but it shows this error:

```
The argument type 'void Function(AdmobAdEvent, Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(AdmobAdEvent, Map<String, dynamic>?)?'
```

I would like to know how to solve this

[image]

Comment: Your tutorial is obsolete and probably older than a year or two. Read up on null safety in dart, a great feature that came out about year ago and was in the development channels way before that.

Comment: thanks bro, i will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error, you may change to this

```dart
listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic>? args) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like nvoigt said, the tutorial it´s obsolete and this is a null safety-related error.

In this case making the method with a `?` after `dynamic` would probably work

```
listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<Stringm, dynamic?>) args {}
```